# Prove that $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^{-n}$ converges to $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a homework question and I am not really sure where to go with it. I have a lot of trouble with sequences and series, can I get a tip or push in the right direction?

Comment: Could you define $e'$?

Comment: I believe it is defined int his homework as just $e$, I will change the OP.

Comment: use $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e$

Comment: @pedja: I think you need the stronger $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$.  (Applied with $x = -1$.)

Comment: Assuming you are to establish the limit, L' Hospital rule may be a good choice.

Comment: @Robjohn: I wonder if your comment is confusing in the current state of the post :) (since the accepted answer has been changed)

Comment: @Ilya: deleted more like. I guess that my comment should have been to that answer. We should leapfrog deletes :-)

Answer (score 62):

You have:
$$
x_n:=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{-n} = \left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{-n} = \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n}
$$
$$
 = \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right) = a_n\cdot b_n.
$$
Since $a_n\to \mathrm e$ and $b_n\to 1$ you obtain what you need.

Comment: Nice solution, uses almost nothing other than the definition of $e$.