# Prove $(1+1/n)^n$ and $(1-1/n)^{-n}$ converge to same number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

Consider the functions: 
\begin{align}
A(n) &= \left(1 + \frac1n \right)^n \\
B(n) &= \left(1 - \frac1n \right)^{-n} \\
C(n) &= 1+\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m!}
\end{align}

Is it possible to show that $A_n$ and $B_n$ converges to the same limit, which is $\lim C_n$ as $n$ toward infinity? Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Regardless of this one being a duplicate or not, allow me to make the links to existing posts: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39170), [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389793), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365029). Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82034) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313506). The list goes on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{A(n)}{B(n)}=\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\to 1 $$
because 
$$ 1\ge \left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\ge 1-\frac1n$$
by Bernoulli's inequality. Therefore, if either of $\lim A(n)$, $\lim B(n)$ exists, so does the other and is equal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!